# Apache2 Block IP with 404 Page or Timeout Error

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, http-status-code-404

Is there any was to configure Apache2 to block certain IPs, but instead of returning a 403 page; do one of the following:

Return a 404 page
Make the connection time out (as it would say in a web browser)
Refuse the connection (again as it would say in a web browser)

The last option would be best for me, but any of those listed would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rewrite module to do it.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.222.333.444$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

taken from this thread on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647599/apache-require-all-denied-http-status-code